# Multipage App's in Meteor 0.8.0 without Iron-Router or any module

Tags: jquery, html, dom, meteor, iron-router

My goal is to switch from one page to another. While I know how to do this with Iron-Router I want to program it myself since I am teaching Meteor to people who have windows, and therefore no Iron-Router.

**Edit:** SUB-QUESTION:Which 3 methods proposed here is more efficient?

My first approach:

```
//HTML
<body>
  {{>mainTemplate}}
</body>

//Cliente JS Initially
Session.set('current', 'initialTemplate')
Template.mainTemplate = function()
{
    return Template[Session.get('current')];
};

//Later
Session.set('current', 'someOtherTemplate')
```

This works in a very Meteoric way BUT it requires a lot of manual strings that are not checked by the IDE and could induce errors. So my second approach is to solve this is:

```
//HTML
<body>
</body>

//JS Client Initially
UI.materialize( Template.initialTemplate, document.body );

//Later
$("body").html("");
UI.materialize( Template.someOtherTemplate, document.body );
```

This second approach uses variables and not strings, it's very readable, shorter, simpler and it works BUT I am a little skeptic about jQuery, I first used it today. Also, I don't know if its really convenient for Meteor's internals to just have chunks of HTML deleted. I Would prefer a pure Meteoric approach if possible.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
This this pattern currently works like a charm! Can somebody find even a simpler one?

```
//HTML
<body>
  {{>mainTemplate}}
</body>

//JS Client Initially
var current = Template.initialTemplate;
var currentDep = new Deps.Dependency;

Template.mainTemplate = function()
{
  currentDep.depend();
  return current;
};

function setTemplate( newTemplate )
{
    current = newTemplate;
    currentDep.changed();
};

//Later
setTemplate( Template.someOtherTemplate );
```

This pattern taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739364/clearing-the-dom-and-rendering-new-page-in-meteor/22744557#22744557) and this seccion in the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency).

Answer (score 1):

I tackled this problem for an app I was building that had only six pages, where adding Iron Router felt like overkill. I built it like this:

```
<body>
{{> root}}
</body>

<template name="root">
  {{#if currentPageIs "home"}}
    {{> home}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if currentPageIs "about"}}
    {{> about}}
  {{/if}}
  {{! etc. }}
</template>
```

And then you define a Session variable `currentPage`, which in my case could be `home` or `about` or the other four page names; and clicking on links or buttons to change pages really only updated the Session variable. Then the helper for this "poor man's router" looks like this:

```
Template.root.currentPageIs = function (page) {
  return Session.equals("currentPage", page);
};
```

And that's it. No jQuery, no working with templates as strings (which should break under Meteor 0.8 with its new templating engine, I would think). It's fully Meteoric. Obviously with more than a handful of pages/routes, this approach gets quite tedious; but it requires no packages and it's very clear to understand for a Meteor novice.

For completeness, here's an example page and the helper to change pages:

```
<template name="home">
  <p>Welcome to our website! You can learn more
  <a href="#" id="goToAbout">about us</a>.</p>
</template>
```

and

```
Template.home.events({
  "click #goToAbout": function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set("currentPage", "about");
  }
});
```

Comment: Question: Where does `page` come from and how do you set it?

Comment: Ok, read a little about handle/space bars, and I think you would still have to do a `Session.set('currentPage', 'somePage');` to switch page wouldn't you?

The problem I have with this is that Session variables are strings, and the variable value is also a manual string.

Comment: If my last comment is true, then your method is equivalent to my first method.

Comment: Your first method returns an entire template: `return Template[Session.get('current')];` whereas my helper just returns true/false, "is the current page X?", and then the `#if` block in the template causes the chosen template to display. That's how you avoid the "returning template HTML" problem.

Comment: And to answer your other question, yes, you need to update the Session variable whenever the user changes pages, however that happens for your app. For example if you have a link with `id="goToHome"` you could have a helper on its template like `"click #goToHome": function (event, template) { event.preventDefault; Session.set("page", "home"); }` And that's all the code you'd need to write; because the templates and helpers and Session are all reactive, the template would redraw automatically.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `Session.set("currentPage", "home");`? Also, while your `#if` approach is explicit, returning the actual template would be more scalable since you could set any NEW template not contemplated in the `#if` scenarios. Note: my approach uses Meteor 0.8.0.

Comment: Any ideas on how to avoid Session variables TOTALLY for this problem?

Comment: Yes, it should be `currentPage`, thanks. You can avoid Session variables by using Iron Router, for one, or by using jQuery; but I think any jQuery solution would be more complicated (and certainly less Meteoric) than a single Session variable. I haven't tried with 0.8 but you might be able to use `UI.render`/`UI.renderWithData` and then `UI.insert` to render a template programmatically and insert it into the DOM, and then I guess jQuery to remove it afterward. If you figure out an elegant way please post your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it but based on your code above I think this would work:

```
//HTML
<body>
  {{>mainTemplate}}
</body>

//Cliente JS Initially
var current = Template.initialTemplate;
var currentDep = new Deps.Dependency;

Template.mainTemplate = function()
{
  currentDep.depend();
  return current;
};

//Later
current = Template.someOtherTemplate;
currentDep.changed();
```

This is just based off your 'ideal' solution but hopefully gets around the Session variable restriction to EJSON-able values.

Comment: Nice pattern! Works great. I'll have to read about the Deps module since at the time your depend() and changed() -while I get the idea because they are readable- are blackmagic to me.
I'll update this as my current ideal pattern but adding a little helper function I currently use in my own inplementation.